# Reactstrap dropdownitem not triggering setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

**What is happening?**

Hello, I'm just using reactstrap and react js for a bit and i have some issues regarding the component. I want to trigger show modal when i click on the component inside the component. this is the module that i've been working for a while:

**What should be happening?**

I expect it to trigger setState when i click the div inside DropdownItem

```
// Base Account placeholder component <PARENT>
export class Account extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            dropDownOpen : false
        };
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            dropDownOpen : !this.state.dropDownOpen
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropDownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                    Account
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownItem>
                        <div onClick={() => console.log("fire pew pew")}>
                        <AccountSettingModal />
                    </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem>
                        Pricings
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem divider />
                    <DropdownItem>
                        Logout
                    </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
}
```

}

this is the modal that i want to show:

```
// Base account placeholder for Modal Setting
class AccountSettingModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: false
        };

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    // console.log("modalSetting: " + this.state.modalSetting);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ****************! trigger this when i click the dropdownitem !*********************
            <div onClick={this.toggle}>
                <a>Setting</a>
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className="account-setting-box">
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Setting</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody className="scroll">
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter className="modal-footer">
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

help much appreciated because i've been dealing with this issues for about two days. I can use custommenu for solving this problem, but in the name of my learning process, I'm convinced that i need to ask about this issue that i got.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are using same name function toggle() in parent and child component, Try to rename toggle() in parent or child component.

Comment: This is also one of my hypotheses as i indulge in this problem. I tried to change the function in the child function to toggleModal(), but to no avail, it didn't work. I also change the name of state and it didn't work. do you have other suggestions mate?

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of the toggle function in the modal as you are using same name function toggle() in parent and child component. Rename `toggle()` in parent or child component and it will be good to go.

```js
// Account
toggleDropdown() {
    this.setState({
        dropDownOpen : !this.state.dropDownOpen
    });
}
```

and/or also change:

```js
// AccountSettingModal
toggleState() {
    this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
    });
}
```